# How to update Clickonce when "The Application Should Check For Updates" checkbox is not checked

Tags: clickonce

By mistake I forgot to check `The Application Should Check For Updates`box. Is there anyway I can update this client application to a newer version?

Comment: Is this related to coding ?

Answer (score 0):

you need your user(s) to uninstall the app and install your new version. Make sure you check the The Application Should Check For Updates box this time.

Here's a link to the update strategies:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx